# Two rectangles are not intersecting when I think they should

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have an enemy rectangle

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
  enemyRectangle = new Rectangle((int)enemyPosition.X, (int)enemyPosition.Y, enemyTexture.Width, enemyTexture.Height);
 ...
```

I have a `foreach` loop, looping through a list of rectangles and a method that checks if these two rectangles have intersected which will return a boolean.

```
foreach (Bounds bounds in bounds.boundsList)
{
  if (bounds.EnemyWallIntersects(testEnemy.enemyRectangle, bounds.CurrentRectangle))
   {
     testEnemy.isEnemyCurrentlyColliding = true;
   }
   testEnemy.isEnemyCurrentlyColliding = false;
 }
```

I am certain these rectangles should be intersecting but I have no clue what is happening now.
I have used a breakpoint and the rectangle is meant to be intersecting with getting to the point where it has the same X and Y as the enemy rectangle.

This is the "EnemyWallIntersects" method.

```
 public bool EnemyWallIntersects(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2)
 {
   if (rect1.Intersects(rect2))
   {
     return true;
   }
   else
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: Post what you see in breakpoint would help others to answer your question.

Comment: As a side note, you can simplify your `EnemyWallIntersects` method by eliminating the `if` statement and instead just do:  `return rect1.Intersects(rect2);`  In fact, you could eliminate that entire method and just use `if (testEnemy.Rectangle.Intersects(bounds.CurrentRectangle))` inside your `foreach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `testEnemy.isEnemyCurrentlyColliding = false;` happens right after setting `testEnemy.isEnemyCurrentlyColliding = true;`, without else statement, so it'll always be set to false.

I'll keep in mind that it's a foreach loop, so even if you put an else statement, the next item in the list would override the `testEnemy.isEnemyCurrentlyColliding` again. If you only need to check if one of them results in true, I recommend using `break`, which will end the current foreach loop.

So as example:

```
foreach (Bounds bounds in bounds.boundsList)
    {
        if (bounds.EnemyWallIntersects(testEnemy.enemyRectangle, bounds.CurrentRectangle))
        {
            testEnemy.isEnemyCurrentlyColliding = true;
            break;
        }
        testEnemy.isEnemyCurrentlyColliding = false;
    }
```

The `else` statement wouldn't be necessary if you're using `break`, because that would end the foreach loop right where it stands.